# Problemas Comunicação Socket Server Delphi Client CSharp

Tags: c#, socket, delphi-7

Tenho a necessidade de implementar uma comunicação via socket com server em [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) e um Client em [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp).

Criei um exemplo e o mesmo faz a comunicação porém por algum motivo o server em [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) quando vai dar o retorno pro [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp) trava a requisição e quando encerro a *App* [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp) no [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) ele continua com a Requisição, esse exemplo é uma `string` que envio um XML somente para multiplicar o valor e retornar o dobro do mesmo.

**Server - Delphi 7 utilizando TcpServer**

```
procedure TForm1.TcpServerAccept(Sender: TObject; ClientSocket: TCustomIpClient);
  var
    rValor: Real;
    sRequisicao: String;

begin
  try
    try
      CoInitialize(nil);
      sRequisicao := ClientSocket.Receiveln;
      memStatus.Lines.Add(sRequisicao);
      XMLDocument1.XML.Text := sRequisicao;
      XMLDocument1.Active := True;

      rValor := StrToFloat(XMLDocument1.ChildNodes.FindNode('reserva').ChildValues['valor']);
      rValor := Self.Multiplicar(rValor);

      XMLDocument1.ChildNodes.FindNode('reserva').ChildValues['valor'] := rValor;
      sRequisicao := XMLDocument1.XML.GetText;
      ClientSocket.Sendln(StringReplace(sRequisicao, sLineBreak, '', [rfReplaceAll]));
    except on e: Exception do
    begin
      memStatus.Lines.Add('Erro: ' + e.Message);
      ClientSocket.Sendln('Erro: ' + e.Message);
    end;
  end;
  finally
     CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

**Client - CSharp - Exemplo tirado da MSDN**

```
static void Send()
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    try
    {
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.164");
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 6500);
        Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
            sender.Connect(remoteEP);
            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?><reserva><valor>1</valor></reserva>");
            int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);
            int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);                    
            Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sender.Close();

        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

No Csharp quando executo e chega na Linha:

```
int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
```

Ele aciona o server no Delphi e fica preso na linha:

```
sRequisicao := ClientSocket.Receiveln;
```

Obs: tenho um Client em Delphi 7 e um Server em Csharp, entre as mesmas linguagens, se comunicam corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri que o problema estava no componente que eu estava utilizando no delphi para criar o server, troquei o Componente TcpServer para o SocketServer ambos da paleta Internet, o código ficou praticamente o mesmo, só mudou as linhas

```
sRequisicao := Socket.ReceiveText;
Socket.SendText(sRequisicao);
```

E na parte do csharp para facilitar utilizei o pacote [Socket](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Socket/2.1.0) que ficou mais simples a utilização.

```
using (var socket = new ConnectedSocket("127.0.0.1", 6500)) 
{
     socket.Send("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?><reserva><valor>10</valor></reserva>");
     var data = socket.Receive(); 
     Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```